# CreateScaledBitmap method returns blurred image when resized the image

Tags: image, bitmap

I have created a bitmap with dimension of 1000x800. When, I am changing this bitmap dimension to 300x120 using Bitmap.CreateScaleBitmap() it gets blur. Is it any possible way to resize bitmap without blur?

please refer the below image for your reference.

[**Original size bitmap:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2gOp.png)

[**Scaled bitmap:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN8pF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try not changing the aspect ratio (which is 5:4).  So, use 300x240 or 150x120.

Comment: Thanks, I want a common solution to scale the bitmap for different dimension and also I tried this, it also returns same blurred image

Comment: If you want a common solution, then you should use SVG instead of raster graphics (like bitmap).